# Where is Displaytag.tld(not jar)

Tags: jsp, displaytag, tld

I am not seeing the `.tld` file in my download folder. I only see JAR files.
What I am missing?

My problem is that, I can't refer like this in my JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
```

I get some error. Hence want to download `.tld` and put it under local `WEB-INF` folder and  then change my JSP like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/displaytag.tld" prefix="display" %>
```

Comment: It would help us if you told us what error you are getting. Having the TLD files within the WEB-INF directory hasn't been a requirement for some years since they're bundled within the tag library JAR.

Comment: Tahnks John.

This is the error I get

Parsing of JSP File '/jsp/cdessSearch.jsp' failed:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 /jsp/cdessSearch.jsp(8): Could not parse deployment descriptor: java.io.IOException: cannot resolve 'http://displaytag.sf.net' into a valid tag library
probably occurred due to an error in /jsp/cdessSearch.jsp line 8:
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>

Comment: Also, why I don't see displaytag/tld in my downloaded folder. They clearly say that it includes jar and tld files. Am I downloading the wrong one?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the loose TLD. It's already inside the JAR file. Just put the downloaded JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib`. That's all. No, not in `/WEB-INF`, this is not covered by the default classpath.

You only need to ensure that the taglib URI is **correct**. Else it will indeed complain about that. The correct one is usually to be found in the documentation of the library in question.

Answer (score 1):

Download displaytag jar and extract this jar file first.  Then, find the METS-INF folder . Inside this META-INF folder, you will find the displaytag.tld file.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to make entry in your web.xml file for your local displaytag.tld file..

```
<jsp-config>
<taglib>
<taglib-uri>
any uri but this must be same as in jsp's uri one
</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>
location of tld file
</taglib-location>
</taglib>
</jsp-config>
```